# PHP confusion while building a script

Tags: php, oop

I am facing some confusion because i have decided to convert from procedural to oop, I Find it more efficient.

So anyway I've got some questions i hope i find answers here :)

Let's say am working on a php Registeration System which requires

1-Signup process
2-Activation Process
3-Login process (which requires)
    Validating inputs
    Validating Sessions, etc

The questions is: Should i make class for every process Or i can combine all of them into one class named 'User', with methods to login, signup, activate and so on, Or can i make 1 class named USER which has user's properties, and signup, login classes extends it ?

1. Should i use separated classes for Sessions, Validating etc ? or just normal Checking inside the main class
2. Should i Separate ADMIN classes from normal classes ? meaning I have a USER class, which has methods, to login user, signup user etc, should i add more functions for admin like DELETE user, UPDATE user ? or separate it from the normal classes

Comment: Please add some capital letters into your English to show that you care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should make a `User` class with different functions for `login` `signup` and whatever.
2. You should separate different functions into as many classes/objects as you feel suits. For instance, with your `User` class you might have a `Session` class which you use within your `User` class to do the session management stuff. You could also create a `Person` class which `User` inherits from. This can have functions like `printFullName` and such, whereas the `User` class has auth specific stuff like `login` and `register`.
3. Again, its up to you. You can do whatever you want. I would probably have a `UserAdmin` class which has functions like `deleteUser($userid)` and `editUser($userid)` just because then its not confusing it with the auth side of things. However it can be done the other way. You could call a `User` object for a specific user and call `deleteUser()` on that to delete the user. Its what you feel most comfortable with.

As with all my answers, its what you want to do. There is no standard to this, and no rules. OOP is mainly about layering everything so that it makes sense, structurally, and about creating reusable code.

Another thing you want to look at is MVC programming. MVC stands for Model, View, Controller. In this set up you actually differentiate objects not by category (e.g. user, page etc) but by their function (e.g. model - connects to a database, view - has the code to layout a page, controller - computes stuff and passes data to the view). If you look at something like codeigniter then this will become more apparent to you.

Now you can create a model for users. In this model you can do all the database stuff, adding, editing, deleting users and such. This can then interface with a controller which will layout the page, e.g. seeing if the user is currently logged in, calling the user's model and getting the name of the user from the model, then passing it to the view to display on screen. This will make much more sense when you start using frameworks like code igniter.

Anyway, good luck in your learning.

Answer (score 0):

It's really your own choice what is in a class and what is not. Mostly it's about what you find to create a good overview and what makes certain use-cases easier. In this case it will most likely cause more confusion if you split these operations, instead of putting them under the same banner.

I'd under most circumstances choose to put validation, signup, etc. in the same class. If admins are also users (and not a whole new table of users for example) I'd also include these in the same class - Or maybe create an admin class that extends the user class.

But there's no ultimate law of what is put in one class and what is not. It's about trial and error and seeing what gives you a good overview, and when you come to building abstraction layers, extending classes, etc. you need to be a little more careful. Taking the right steps can save you a ton of work in later work with extending classes.

Answer (score 0):

I made the switch about 6 months ago from functional to OOP. I read a shitload of papers trying to figure out what the big deal about OOP is.

I think a conceptual understanding is important in this case. Think of an object as a physical thing.

A car:

A car has properties:

- color
- remaining petrol
- top speed

A car has methods:

- start
- stop
- accelerate.

1) A user is an object, login, logout, signup are actions/methods that a user does.

2) A user has session variables(properties) so I would place them as properties in the class

3) An admin user has more methods, but still needs acess to old ones. So idealy an admin user should inherit the properties and methods, I think this is done with the Extends keyword. This is called subclassing, or inhertance.

You best is to google "understanding oop concepts" and read whatever connects with you

Comment: True, thinking about class as a physical object helped me understanding lots of oop concepts, thanks for your Answer :)

Comment: Happy to help dude, I'm new to this stack overflow game anyway it's kinda fun

Comment: Yeah its cool, specially that you get answers quickly, and lots of awesome people ready to help here :)